# www.Bo.lt, or how to make a copy a entire webpage including children files

Tags: php, javascript

as you may have noticed service like Bo.lt allow you to edit a website and show the results.
As far as I understood they make a copy of a website first

like in http://lll.bo.lt/ev5ct

so, my question is, in order to achieve it, what's the best practice to pull all the page or  DOM form the page, and copy it to my server, including the children files?

i know it sounds a big question, but i just need orientation if is doable in php / javascirpt

Comment: There's already a utility for this: `wget --recursive`

Comment: Yes, doable in PHP and JS, and yes, you'd probably need to download all the files and serve them yourself. This is partly because, if you want the files to editable, you need to store them someplace where you can change them; also, some site owners won't like a service such as this hotlinking their asset files, and may block them. (Of course, if you are building such a thing, you should consider site owners' wishes if they do not want their site editable - maybe via robots.txt?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used CURL and was way faster and easier.

Answer (score 0):

@Frank Farmer has it right with that.  You can also write a little spider to index links, crawl them, and store them.  That'll give you the exercise to learn how to do it.